# quote all during df to csv in julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

is there a way to double quote all fields when outputting a DataFrame to a csv in Julia? I am having trouble find an answer with Google.

In python I would add `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` to `df.to_csv(file)`

I am having trouble finding something similar with `CSV.write(file,df)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
julia> using CSV, DataFrames

julia> io = IOBuffer()
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf,ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> df = DataFrame(rand(1:10, 3, 5), :auto)
3×5 DataFrame
 Row │ x1     x2     x3     x4     x5
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼───────────────────────────────────
   1 │     6     10      5      4      4
   2 │     1      9      6      5      3
   3 │     5      4      5      8      4

julia> CSV.write(io, df; quotestrings=true, transform=(col,val)->string(val)) |> take! |> String |> println
"x1","x2","x3","x4","x5"
"6","10","5","4","4"
"1","9","6","5","3"
"5","4","5","8","4"
```

The trouble is that `quotestrings` only forces quoting strings (so that when you read back the file numbers are not quoted and correctly parsed) and therefore you need also `transform` argument to force every value to be written as string.

Comment: Thank you for that. I just started learning Julia and that is one of the main things I'll need in my day to day. With Python, I generally bring in as strings and temp format as int, float,...